# Lazy Highcharts drilldown mvc asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I need to load the data for the drill down charts on click rather than on page load.

```
//Drill down for yearly periods
    @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <text>
         @item.QuestionType = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: '@item.Category.CategoryName'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '@item.QuestionType Over the last year'
            },
            series: [{
                name: '@item.QuestionType over the last year',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Yes',
                    y:@Html.Action("GetYear", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes" }),
                    drilldown: '@item.QuestionType-Month',
                }, {
                    name: 'No',
                    y: @Html.Action("GetYear", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No" }),
                    drilldown: '@item.QuestionType-Month',
                }]
            }]

        };
        </text>
        }



     //Drill down for entire periods per category

     @foreach(var cat in categories)
    {
        <text>
     @cat.CategoryName = {
         chart: {
             type: 'column'
         },
         title: {
             text: '@cat.CategoryName'
         },
         xAxis: {
             type: 'category',
             title: {
                 text: 'Categories in @cat.CategoryName'
             }
         },
         yAxis: {
             allowDecimals: false,
             title: {
                 text: 'Questions answered'
             }
         },
         plotOptions: {
             column: {
                 stacking: 'normal'
             }
         },
         series: [

             {
                 name: 'Yes',
                 data: [
                     @foreach(var item in Model)
                {
                        if(@item.CategoryID == @cat.CategoryID)
                        {
                            <text>
                         {
                             name: '@item.QuestionType',
                             y: @Html.Action("GetQuestion", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "Yes" }),
                             drilldown: @item.QuestionType,

                         },
                     </text>
                        }

                    }
                 ],
             }, {
                 name: 'No',
                 data: [
               @foreach(var item in Model)
                {
                  if(@item.CategoryID == @cat.CategoryID)
            {
                            <text>
                         {
                             name: '@item.QuestionType',
                             y: @Html.Action("GetQuestion", new { id = @item.QuestionID, category = "No" }),
                             drilldown: @item.QuestionType,

                         },
                        </text>
            }
        }
                 ]
             }]
     };
    </text>
        }



    //loop for first level
    $("#container").highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {

            text: 'All categories'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Questions answered'
            },

            allowDecimals: false,},

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            },
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: "All categories",
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [ @foreach(var item in categories)
                {
                <text>{
                name: '@item.CategoryName',
                y: @Html.Action("GetCategory", new {id = item.CategoryID}),
                drilldown: @item.CategoryName,
            },
            </text>
                }
            ]
        }]

    });
```

The current code all runs on page load making the load time over 14s,
I want to be able to load the correct method when a certain point on the chart is clicked.

Ive seen examples like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/basic/) but when i try and implement it, it does not display. I think i may be struggling because i have stacked columns and this code is for a normal column, also i need to change the layout of the chart when drilling down, such as title category ect, which this code does not do.

Comment: See [chart.events.drilldown](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown) - there you can find a demo with ascync drilldown. In that event update also everything on the chart you want to.

Comment: @PawełFus thanks for the link, i have tried it before, my problem with it is that i have to change chart types at some point and i dont know where to insert the code for a change in chart:{} options.

Comment: You can't change "chart" options in real time, except destroying and recreating the chart. What option exactly you want to change?

Comment: @PawełFus, ok so i got the drill down to work for a single column, now im trying to use my code for a stacked column. but i dont know the correct format to put the code in in the events{drilldown:function(e){ part.

you can see the code im using in my original post under //drilldown for entire periods per category.

the second problem is that after the initial drilldown event i need to drilldown further into a piechart and im not sure where the event for that would go

Comment: Have you set: [`allowPointDrilldown`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#drilldown.allowPointDrilldown) to false? Regarding pie chart - set for drilldown series `type: "pie"`.

Comment: @PawełFus thank you for the help.
i have one last issue. the final chart load takes around 10seconds when initially loaded.
is there anyway to decrease this load time or write it more efficiently

Comment: Hard to say, maybe slow connection to the server?